# User control with a dependency property in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

A newbie question. After googling for hours, I still can't get a *clean* answer for this (standarad) situation.

I have a UserControl_1 that will consist of one custom control and one WPF control. The user control is to be used on other WPF UserControls.

Ultimately, I would like to do this in the XAML of the Main user control:

```
  XAML
      <i:UserControl_1  TargetDP = "{Binding SourceProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" }" />
```

Where the SourceProperty is bound to the DataContext of the Main user control, and the TargetDP is a dependency property in the UserControl_1. UserControl_1 is then to pass this TargetDP down/up to its contained controls.

So where do I put the DependencyProperty for the UserControl?

It seems like it should go in the code-behind, but I'd really like to do this using MVVM.

UserControl_1 should have its own ViewModel separate from the Main User control, but information should be able to pass between the main view model and the user control view model (and visa versa) via the UserControl XAML bindings.

Thanks for any help or clarification on this. (Sorry if this seems a duplicate, but none of the other articles seem to specify where to create a new dependency property of a user control or how to achieve this).

Comment: You mean you don't know where to put the binding declaration in UserControl_1's XAML?

Comment: @Clemens Where to declare a new dependency property for UserControl_1? i.e., in the UserControl_1's viewmodel (if that is possible), or in the UserControl_1.XAML.cs (the code behind)?

Comment: @Clemens And if it is declared in the code-behind file, how then to have the dependency properties use the viewmodel (or visa versa)?

Comment: A dependency property of a user control is declared in the user control's code behind, i.e. UserControl_1.xaml.cs here. You could then bind this dependency property to any view model like you did in your example in your question. The controls in the user control's XAML could also bind to the property, by using a relative source binding with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}`.

Comment: @Clemens How do I use the code-behind for the dependency properties, and still use a separate viewmodel for the user control business logic?

Comment: The control's code-behind contains the dependency property declaration. The property is then bound to a view model property. Property declaration and binding are independent things. I'd suggest to get a book or online tutorial about MVVM with WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how this can be done (if I understand you correctly!). You have a user control, call it `MyControl`. Create the `MyControlView`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Controls.MyControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="5,0"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now the view model would be

```
public class MyControlViewModel
{
    // Add the public properties for LabelText, ComboBoxItems and SelectedItem
    // and any other logic you require.
}
```

Now for the bit you are confused over. If I want to consume this control in another view, call it `BigView` I can do

```
<Window x:Class="NameSpace.BigView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Project.Controls"> // Important reference to your control namespace.
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Controls:MyControlView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,5" 
                                DataContext="{Binding MyControlA}"/>
        <Controls:MyControlView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5" 
                                DataContext="{Binding MyControlB}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now in the view model `BigViewModel` you will have two properties

```
public RangeSliderControlViewModel MyControlA { get; set; }
public RangeSliderControlViewModel MyControlB { get; set; }
```

So then you can access each controls properties via `MyControlA.LabelText = "Some Text"` et al. Note, that in the `BigViewModel` the `MyControlA`/`MyControlB` do not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` however, the properties in you control *must* in order for the updates to bubble up and update `BigView`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Kilercam In creating MyControl, if I have a new dependency property, targetDP, is that placed in MyControlViewModel.cs or in MyControl.XAML.cs (the code-behind)? Thanks.

Comment: @Kilercam Can the target dependency property be placed in the "DataContext"? of the MyControlView? Thanks.

Comment: @Kilercam It seems that in the above the BigViewModel is setting the DataContext of the user control, but does this not require the BigViewModel to have intimate knowledge of the usercontrol? Something I'd like to avoid. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean by "intimate knowlegde". All that `BigViewmodel` needs is a reference to the namespace that contains the user control. That's it. It does not need to do any logic handling as this is delegated to the underlying controls view model. For dependency properties you can put it in the code behind for things like this - there are MVVM purist that will go mental about this (I used to be one!), but once you gain more experience, you realize that there is not much point in fighting the pattern in certain cases. The other options...

Comment: ... for DPs is to first create your user control, then inherit from this control and embellish it with you dependency properties - this is not very clean though. Another option is to use `System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior`s to add bindable properties to your control. I think here, code behind is okay.

Comment: If I put the dependency properties in the code-behind, does this necessitate putting the rest of the usercontrols's business logic also in the code-behind (and abandon the "viewmodel" approach) ?? Thanks much.

Comment: No, not at all, put the rest of the logic in the ViewModel. It is just that for DP's you need direct references to the view. For any thing else, put in the view model. Note, you have other options if you do not want the DPs in the code behind - there always other options.

Comment: Thank you for the cleanest explanation I have yet to find. Combining this with RelativeSource as stated above led to a working solution.

Comment: Umm...as posted in my newer question, when the DataContext is set explicitly on the UserControl with "DataContext=...", the display is blank? Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66320/discussion-between-alan-wayne-and-killercam).

Comment: Found the error...I was incorrectly initializing the DataContext. Thanks.